# creating a panel kind of functionality in xcode like it is present in bootstrap

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am looking to create panel kind of functionality in my app. I am using iOS 10 and swift 3. 
It should look like

> Login       + 
>   Register    -

Like it is shown down.
[image]
I would like to have functionality like when I touch login or that row till + sign then sign becomes - and it drop down fields which is holding username and password text box. Means login box gets expanded with login fields and at same time register bar minimizes its fields, And vice versa. I am confused how to approach this design problem. I don't know their is direct way like it is in bootstrap. If not kindly suggest me little approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take tableView and Put login label and `+` button on header programmatically.Take textField inside the cell and make toggle after click on `+` button.